# List<T>: searching list items which have property contains value c#

Tags: c#, list, linq, where-clause

i've tried to do this

model class is:

```
public class Model
{
    public string Title{ get; set; }
    public int PartId { get; set; }
    public bool Valid { get; set; }    
}
```

With this i get all films from db:

```
 List<Model> movies = this._context.ExecuteQuery<Model>(querystring).ToList();
```

I've tried to get all movie which titles contains (not equal) the word "monster"

```
List<Model> results = movies.Where(c=> c.Title.Contains("monster"));
```

Comment: We need more information. Is it LinqToSql or EntityFw ?

Comment: What exactly is `movies`? It's obviously not a simple `List<Model>` but some kind of query of a queryprovider like Linq2Sql or EntityFramework...

Comment: The code, as is, does not compile. `List<Model> results = movies.Where(c=> c.Title.Contains("monster"));` Given the answer you have marked, I have removed the incorrect part of your question (which stated you had an exception, when in reality you have a compile time error).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to understand how linq/deferred execution works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25781982/trying-to-understand-how-linq-deferred-execution-works)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List<Model> results = movies.Where(c=> c.Title.Contains("monster"));`

is incomplete. You need to add an operator after using `Where()` - in your case, you maybe want `.ToList()`:

`List<Model> results = movies.Where(c=> c.Title.Contains("monster")).ToList();`

(or change your `List<Model>` to `IEnumerable<Model>`, or even `var`)

Comment: Though it's correct that OP is missing a `.ToList()`, this does not explain the error message OP receives.

Comment: @RenéVogt Maybe, because he tries to evaluate the expression within visual studio? (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36559399/lambda-expressions-in-immediate-window-for-vs2015) (Only a guess, its nowhere mentioned)

Comment: @davidelondei because the return type of `where()` is `IEnumerable<TSource>`. Not all `IEnumerable<TSource>` are `List<TSource>`, hence you either need to work with `IEnumerable` or call `ToList(), ToArray(), First(), FirstOrDefault(),....` to either get an `List<T>, Array<T> or T,...`.

Comment: also you maybe want to use `c.Title.ToLower().Contains("monster")`, if your search should be case-insensitive.

Comment: Please be aware, that every time you call `.ToList()` you actually send a request to your database. That might not be what you want. For example if you 'prepare' a query, which is some lines under it used to join a different table. Try to send queries as little as possible.

Comment: @nilsK In this specific instance, the change that dognose proposed would not send a query to the database (since `movies` is already a `List<Model>`).

Comment: @mjwills yes, you are right. Thanks for mentioning!